# Physical significance of magnitude of ΔG (change in Gibbs free energy) of a reaction

Tags: thermodynamics

In thermodynamics, we know that if $\Delta G$ of a reaction is negative, the reaction is spontaneous.

Suppose we are given with two spontaneous reactions ($\Delta G\lt0$) with corresponding magnitudes of $\Delta G$. Can we extract any other information from these magnitudes?

Comment: Are the reactions simultaneous or are they independent .

Comment: @ChakravarthyKalyan I was thinking about 2 independent reactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only a rule of thumb that a negative value for $\Delta G^0$ of a reaction means that a reaction is spontaneous.  If you start out with pure reactants (and no products present), all reactions are spontaneous, irrespective of the $\Delta G^0$.  A negative value for $\Delta G^0$ only signifies that the equilibrium constant is greater than 1.

Comment: I never liked "spontaneous" when discussing equilibrium, only when discussing Q, for exactly the reason you point out. My understanding is that dG std simply states whether the reaction is product or reactant favored under the specified standard state conditions.

Answer (score -1):

The change in the Gibbs free energy for a process at a constant temp. and pressure is equal to how much non-expansion work it can do.